# How to run ScalaTests with Intellij in a Mill Project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest, mill

I have a Scala Project building with Mill.

My ScalaModule is `e2e`.

Running my tests work on the console, like:

`mill e2e.test`

However running it as an *Intellij ScalaTest* it does not pick up my `application.conf`

The configuration looks fine - it says *Use classpath of module:* `e2e.test`

Do I miss something or is not possible yet with Intellij?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely I could fix this by moving `resources` folder from `test` to `e2e` and back again.

So it seems there was some inconsistency in my Intellij project.